# simple logic question: check if x is between 2 numbers

Tags: logic, compare, range

I want to see if a variable is between a range of values, for example if x is between 20 and 30 return true.

What's the quickest way to do this (with any C based language)?

It can obviously be done with a for loop:

```
function inRange(x, lowerbound, upperbound)
{
  for(i = lowerbound; i < upperbound; i++)
  {
    if(x == i) return TRUE;
    else return FALSE;
  }
}
//in the program
if(inRange(x, 20, 30))
   //do stuff
```

but it's awful tedious to do `if(inRange(x, 20, 30))` is there simpler logic than this that doesn't use built in functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression you want is

```
20 <= x && x <= 30
```

EDIT:

Or simply put in in a function

```
function inRange(x, lowerbound, upperbound)
{
  return lowerbound <= x && x <= upperbound;
}
```

Python has an `in` operator:

```
>>> r = range(20, 31)
>>> 19 in r
False
>>> 20 in r
True
>>> 30 in r
True
>>> 31 in r
False
```

Also in Python, and this is pretty cool -- comparison operators are chained!  This is totally unlike C and Java.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Comparison_operators

So you can write

```
low <= x <= high
```

In Python `-10 <= -5 <= -1` is True, but in C it would be false.  Try it. :)

Comment: an inrange operator would be very handy in C-based languages

Answer (score 3):

Why not just `x >= lowerbound && x <= upperbound` ?

Comment: I was drawing a blank here and for some reason, just couldn't think of this... thanks